# ValueError: shuffle must be either True or False, got True

Tags: python, machine-learning, boolean, hyperparameters

I found best hyperparameter grid for my MLP Regressor and i set that in my model by

```
model=model0.set_params(**best_grid)
```

When then i try to fit the model by

```
mod1=model.fit(X_pp, y)
```

I get

```
ValueError: shuffle must be either True or False, got True.
```

`best_grid` is:

```
{'activation': 'relu',
 'alpha': 0.1,
 'batch_size': 'auto',
 'beta_1': 0.9,
 'beta_2': 0.9,
 'early_stopping': True,
 'epsilon': 1e-07,
 'hidden_layer_sizes': [62, 31, 48],
 'learning_rate': 'constant',
 'learning_rate_init': 0.01,
 'max_fun': 15000,
 'max_iter': 10000,
 'momentum': 0.6,
 'n_iter_no_change': 10.0,
 'nesterovs_momentum': True,
 'power_t': 0.5,
 'random_state': None,
 'shuffle': True,
 'solver': 'sgd',
 'tol': 0.1,
 'validation_fraction': 0.1,
 'verbose': False,
 'warm_start': False}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How many parameters are you trying to optimize in your grid-search?

Comment: I did a massive grid of 23 parameters with random search. I run Random Search many times and each time I collected results of the best solution in a db to compare them. Then I estracted the best grid from the best of this db as the dict called "best_grid". No problem when i set_params() but when i fit it I get the error.

Comment: I solved the problem through a dummy escape. I just set directly the problematic parameters as follow:<br/> best_grid['shuffle']=True
best_grid['nesterovs_momentum']=True
best_grid['early_stopping']=True
best_grid['random_state']=None <br/> Could you please help me understand why was my grid wrong?

Comment: That's weird, not sure why setting the parameters as a Key-Value pair outside the definition works. So there is an existing/similar issue for [this](https://github.com/rodrigo-arenas/Sklearn-genetic-opt/issues/77). You can maybe raise your own issue on the github repo.

Comment: Is ` best_grid` the `best_params_` from the hyperparameter tuner? Which hyperparameter tuner? What class is `model0`? What do you get by running `model.get_params()`? Is one of those `True`s secretly a string?